# opening excel file after save with blob having issues suddenly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, ms-office

I have a weird bug - I have a JS function to create an Excel file for download, this is the code:

> ```
> $scope.loadScript('js/fileSaver.js', 'text/javascript', 'utf-8');         setTimeout(function () {
>    var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
>    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"
>   });
>   saveAs(blob, "excel.xls");
> }, 1000);
> ```

The file is being downloaded correctly, and worked great till now, it seems like Microsoft Office changed something that now when users try to open the file the file is not opening at all with no error at all.

With old office versions it's still working.

I am struggling to find a solution for that online.

Do you have any idea how to resolve it?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

try it by changing `type` value from

```
type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"
```

to

```
type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel'
```

Comment: i am using same this type but in microsoft excel i am not getting cells i am getting only values how to solve this problem @Gavishiddappa Gadagi